# Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_SKStoreReviewController when testing Gamemaker Studio 2 Project

Tags: ios, xcode, gml, game-maker-studio-2

I am attempting to test my Gamemaker Studio 2 Project through Xcode as usual, but since updating to Xcode 11.2.1 my game compiles and tests fine on a simulator device but whenever I attempt to push to my test device I receive this error:[image: Error Log from Xcode]

Any idea what I can do to try and solve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out finally, all I had to do was go to Targets > my_app > general and then under Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content hit the little plus icon and add StoreKit.framework to my project and it worked perfectly!